# How to deal with this error 'The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: isNotEmpty'

Tags: flutter, dart

I was writing code to upload files to firebase. I came across this error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#70834):
The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isNotEmpty
```

I am pasting few lines of code here for your reference. Please let me know if you need more info. Thank you.

```
.
.   
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String fileName = p.basename(sampleFile?.path);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `p.basename(sampleFile?.path)`.

But when `sampleFile` is `null`, `sampleFile?.path` results in a null.

So inside `basename` function, there must be a `.isNotEmpty` check on a string but you are passing it as null;

If `basename` function is yours, then refactor the code to handle `null` values as well.

Otherwise, if `basename` is not your function, then use it like this.

```
String? fileName = null;
if (sampleFile?.path != null) fileName = p.basename(sampleFile?.path);
```

Then, change your usage of the `fileName` accordingly in the rest of your code.

Comment: Was this something you were looking for ?